# QGIS create point data attribute as the name of the polygon it falls in

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, statistics

I'm working in QGIS with a point data set overlaying a farm with 140 fields. While I can analyse the points from each field individually, I would rather use an awk script to calculate statistics I need.

The problem is that I am unable to import the containing polygon_id as an attribute into the point table.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do a spatial join (to get the name of the polygon a point is in).  Go to Vector->Data Management Tools->Join Attributes by location.